# How do I test a component with a module dependency in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, nuxt.js

I have a Vue application that I've built on top of Nuxt. I make heavy use of DayJS and have installed the [`@nuxtjs/dayjs`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dayjs-module) Nuxt module which binds `this.$dayjs` to the Vue instance and `$dayjs` to the Nuxt context.

I have built a component that takes advantage of the module, using `this.$dayjs` in several places. I want to test this component using Jest but even the following simple mounting test...

```
describe('Timeline component', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Timeline)

  it('renders a Vue instance', () => {
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

...yields this error

> TypeError: this.$dayjs is not a function

This makes sense. Normally, when testing Vue components you have to add your plugins to a local Vue instance.

```
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(dayjs)
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this when the plugin is part of a Nuxt component.

Is there an official way of importing the Vue plugin portion of a Nuxt module to use in tests?

Comment: @Ken not that I recall. Some of this may have changed in Vue 3 + Nuxt 3 as well.